# SSAS cube design, semi-additive measures, and running totals

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, cubes

I have what is to me a bit of a tricky design issue in my SSAS cube.  The question is related to general accounting practices, I have a fact table containing financial transactions (i.e. a ledger) and each of those transactions is tagged with a transaction date and a period.  The period does NOT related directly to a day, or a series of days.  Users may close a period in the middle of a day if that is when they have finished their months work.

I need to be able to report on Accounts Receivable (AR) by both date and period.  I am not using Enterprise Edition of SSAS so the time intelligence semi-additive options are not availabe to me, and even if they were they would only allow one time dimension to use non-standard aggregation and I believe in this case I need two that allow this.

Accounts Receivable is a running total, it should be the sum of the latest ledger item selected and everything that came before it.  I know how do do this calculation in MDX for a single time dimension, but how can I allow this to work with two time dimensions, transaction date, and period close?  Is period close even considered a "time" dimension in this case?  It does have a temporal aspect to it, and I do want the sums from all periods up to the current.

I am stumped on how to related the two time dimensions to a single fact table and use different aggregation for each.  Maybe the best solution here is to have two periodic snapshot tables (instead of trying to aggregate this info from the FactLedger table), one aggregated by transaction date and one by period which is the solution I am currently leaning towards but I would love a second opinion.

Comment: To clarify, a Period in accounting sense is a period of time but it may not be the same for all locations in the cube.  Say I have two locations, one chooses to close their January period on February 2nd, the other location chooses to close their period on February 4th (it is generally the first week of the following month but I have no control over this).  I cannot just use a standard time dimension but there is still definitely a time (or at least serial) component to this as the February period will always follow the January period.

Answer (score 1):

You can most certainly have more than one time dimension in a cube, and in this case I would actually just create one common time dimension and have it role play as two, transaction date and period close. To role play a dimension, just add it to the cube again in the Dimension Usage tab of the cube designer and rename it. Set up your references appropriately to key off of the two different fact columns.

Or maybe I'm not understanding the issue correctly. This sounds pretty straight-forward.

Comment: That's going to get messy if you have a time dimension with defined and regular entries e.g. one row per day, or one row per hour, then in addition to this, have a random dimension which just has start and end points created by the user whenever they start/finish their work

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own time-table with periods and you can alter your fact_table's datetime format to match your time-table. Then 1 dimension would be enough.